# Parsing disks in zpool

Tags: shell, solaris, zfs

I am looking for a simplest way to parse disks in zpool.
A list of disks in space separated format.
For example below output shows zpool information. Is there any command to get list of physical disks only?

```
   # zpool status pool
      pool: pool
      state: ONLINE
      scan: none requested
      config:

            NAME       STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
            pool       ONLINE       0     0     0
              c2d44s2  ONLINE       0     0     0
              c2d45s2  ONLINE       0     0     0
              c2d46s2  ONLINE       0     0     0

    errors: No known data errors
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work although it might need some fixes for complex `zpool status` output :

```
# cat parsezs
awk '
  NF != 5 {next}
  $1 == "NAME" {getline;show=1;next}
  $1 ~ "mirror" {next}
  $1 ~ "raidz" {next}
  $1 ~ "replacing" {next}
  $1 ~ "error" {next}
  show == 1 {printf("%s ",$1)}
  END {printf("\n")}'
# zpool status pool | parsezs
c2d44s2 c2d45s2 c2d46s2
```

Comment: It would be convenient if ZFS provide JSON format output :(

Comment: @Chien-WeiHuang Yes, that would help. There is unfortunately no flag to get a parsable output.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work and shows you the pool name too.  Note that you need `nawk`, which is a more modern version of Awk on Solaris:

```
zpool status  | nawk 'BEGIN{Disp=0}{if($1=="pool:") {if(Disp!=0) print ""; else Disp = 1; printf("%s ",$2)} ; if($1~"^c[0-9]") printf("%s ",$1)}END{print ""}'
```

The `Disp` variable is just to tidy up the output.  This is a typcal result:

```
js_data_san c0t6006016049B13A00B337B4F7F1DDE411d0 c0t6006016093003B0022E5A8A8C833E711d0
rpool c0t5000CCA07D07C764d0 c0t5000CCA07D07C514d0
s10patchchk-ospool c0t6006016093003B00B488CFCF10D8E611d0
vmware_ds_nfs01 c0t6006016049B13A005AE1A9648112E511d0
```

So in that example `rpool` and `js_data_san` each has two devices.  It doesn't indicate if they are mirrored or concatenated, but that would be easy to change in the script.